# How to overwrite a function that is in an external .js file with one in the .html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I must be missing something here?

If I have a function in say your.js file like:

```
function sayHi(){
   alert('Hi there');
}
```

Then in the html file I have:

```
...
<head>
...
<script>your.js</script>
<script>
function sayHi(){
   alert("G'day mate.");
}
...
```

Why do I get the "Hi there", I thought that the one in the html file would over write the one in the js file?

Couple of points, the your.js file cannot be changed or replaced and the html file is loaded via an iFrame so it has no body section and I cannot change anything except the html file.
I have done this before in a subsequent .js file but not in an html file, any ideas?

Comment: it depends on how/where sayHi is defined and where it's called from.

Comment: show your complete code i didn't see any iFrame in your code

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dan, it is defined in the your.js and is called from within the your.js but after the html call another (different) function in the your.js - thanks

Comment: Thanks Shailendra, I have tried to make this simple and I don't have any control of how the html file is loaded and I cannot change the your.js file - thanks.

Comment: Overwrite the function in an onload. The inline function will almost always be defined first, since you'll start parsing the html before the html fetches the external script defined in the html.

Comment: Thanks Shilly, there's no body, the entire html consists of head only.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my solution is :

```
<script id="your-js" data-src="./your.js"></script>
<script>
    var sayHi;
    window.onload = function () {
        var yourJs;
        yourJs = document.querySelector("#your-js");
        yourJs.setAttribute("src", yourJs.getAttribute("data-src"));
        yourJs.onload = function () {
            sayHi = function () {
                alert("G'day mate.");
            };
        };
    };
</script>
```

---

Besides,I tried `your code` in some browsers(firefox,safari,chrome), but none of them like yours(alert G'day mate.).

I think its a mechanism called `lookahead pre-parser`(or `preloader` in chrome). Browser always prepared two parsers, main parser parsing normal resources, and another parser in charge of parsing resources that is heavyweight(like external js,stylesheet,image).
For this reason, .js files not always loaded in order.

But(!) I thinked it over, then I surround the code inside .js file with `window.onload` like :

```
var sayHi;
window.onload = function (){
    sayHi = function (){
        alert('Hi there');
    }
};
```

Then I get the same result like yours(alert 'Hi there').
`window.onload` will execute after whole page are loaded.

May this will helpful  :/